# Can i update store listing on play console without updating any apk version or other stuff? My app is already published

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, android-update-app

***I want to update my application's store listing without updating anything else.***

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can change anything in the store listing section without updating the APK. Once you change and publish your updates like metadata, graphical assets & other things, it takes approximately 5-6 minutes, then It will be changed on Google Play Store without notifying your existing user.

Comment: It has been two days also, still no updates.

Comment: @genericUser Did you have to do something?

Comment: Hey @wamae I have added my own answer :) worked for me

Answer (score 8):

**Yes**, you can update your page regardless updating the app version.

It's not so intuitive, but once you update your `store listing` you need to **submit your changes** for review at the `Publishing overview`.

### If you don't do that, it will take a long time till Google will review your changes.

1. Update your `main store listing`
   [image]
2. Submit your changes to review at the `Publishing overview`
   [image]

After submitting your changes, it should take about an hour for their approval (and maybe another hour to take effect at the store).

Comment: Yes, this is the solution, It also worked for me. Thanks.